# How to get server MOTD on non-server install

Tags: server, ssh, landscape

Is there a way to get the fancy MOTD that shows up on an Ubuntu Server install on my Ubuntu Alternate install? Like this:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 11.10 (GNU/Linux 3.0.0-12-server x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/C

  System information as of Sun Nov  6 00:38:01 PDT 2011

  System load:  0.0                Processes:           88
  Usage of /:   0.8% of 227.98GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 14%                IP address for eth0: 10.13.37.147
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at https://landscape.canonical.com/
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Posting this as an answer since Stefano Palazzo thought it would be a good idea.

The dynamic MOTD is part of the 'landscape-common' package. So just install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install landscape-common
```

Comment: Just as a note to anyone else:  after installing landscape-common, it took a few minutes and a couple of SSH logins to finally see the desired MOTD.  Not sure why this is, perhaps /etc/update-motd.d is parsed on a CRON of some sort.