# How can I get available updates to show at login?

Tags: updates, login-screen

While playing around with Amazon EC2, I noticed that the Ubuntu images showed available updates at login (See pic)

How can I get my home installation to do this? I'm running 14.04.

[image: Amazon EC2 Welcome]

My question is specifically in reference to packages/security updates. In the image, they are represented as "0 packages can be updated." and "0 updates are security updates." All other information showed up without the fix that I referenced as a comment to the duplication flag. I've discovered two solutions for the problem:

- Running **tasksel** allows the selection of the **Basic Ubuntu server** collection
- An abbreviated form of **tasksel** appears at the end of a fresh installation, which also allows the selection of **Basic Ubuntu server**

Comment: Installing the Ubuntu server packages at the end of the installation resolved the problem. There was no need to manually edit the MOTD configuration or install landscape-common.

Comment: if you did find a fix, you could add it as answer to help anyone in the future that finds this

Comment: I would, but I seem to be unable to since it is marked as a duplicate, which it is not.

Comment: Hi somehume, welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Did the answer to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75997/how-to-get-server-motd-on-non-server-install) not solve your issue or had you already resolved it? It looks to me like you both are asking the same thing. If that is the case I suggest you post your answer over there instead. Feel free to reply if you have any questions or if I am perhaps misunderstanding something. Thanks!

Comment: The answer in the linked question does not solve my problem; I'm specifically interested in updates, which the linked question does not address. My solution does seem to additionally solve the problem in the linked question. What do you suggest under these circumstances.

Comment: My question is specifically in reference to packages/security updates. In the image, they are represented as "0 packages can be updated." and "0 updates are security updates." All other information showed up without the fix that I referenced as a comment to the duplication flag. I've discovered two solutions for the problem:

Running tasksel allows the selection of the Basic Ubuntu server collection

An abbreviated form of tasksel appears at the end of a fresh installation, which also allows the selection of Basic Ubuntu server

...also, how do I get this question unflagged as a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`update-motd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/update-motd.5.html) to execute `apt-get --dry-run update; apt-get --dry-run dist-upgrade` (or whatever you feel is close enough to what you would to to, hmm, *update* your system).

Comment: Will a dry-run actually get any useful information?

Comment: @Seth Wouldn't it? What would you deem useful?

Comment: Dry-run *simulates* changes, nothing would actually happen, and the `update` command doesn't support the option either.

Comment: @Seth The OP wanted only a list of available updates to be shown, and no real update. Sorry if I was wrong regarding --dry-run availability. Can't rtefine my answert, though -- turned my back on Ubuntu. It's not the right distribution for me.